# HTML/CGI: When linking, append variable/value pair instead of replacing?

Tags: html

If on page foo.php I have a link with `<a href=?bar=baz>Click</a>`, that link will bring a user to foo.php?bar=baz. But what if the user is already on foo.php?bar=baz, and I want to link them to foo.php?bar=baz&qux=derp, is there a way to express this in the href attribute of the a tag? If my tag is `<a href=?qux=derp>Click</a>` then the user is directed to foo.php?qux=derp instead of foo.php?bar=baz&qux=derp.

Thanks!

I tagged this as CGI because I think the ?bar=baz part of the URL is more related towards that, but please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do so. You will need to parse the current URL and add the new parameter appropriately.

Comment: Thought so, but was hoping against myself! Thanks for the help.